# lensfun install failure

Tags: software-installation, darktable, lensfun

```
[sudo] password for ykarant: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libflashrom1 libftdi1-2 libllvm13 libllvm13:i386
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  python3-lensfun
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  liblensfun-bin python3-lensfun
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 7 not upgraded.
Need to get 28.4 kB of archives.
After this operation, 108 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Get:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/universe amd64 python3-lensfun amd64 0.3.2-6 [10.1 kB]
Get:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/universe amd64 liblensfun-bin amd64 0.3.2-6 [18.2 kB]
Fetched 28.4 kB in 1s (32.1 kB/s)         
Selecting previously unselected package python3-lensfun.
(Reading database ... 561169 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../python3-lensfun_0.3.2-6_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking python3-lensfun (0.3.2-6) ...
Selecting previously unselected package liblensfun-bin.
Preparing to unpack .../liblensfun-bin_0.3.2-6_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking liblensfun-bin (0.3.2-6) ...
Setting up python3-lensfun (0.3.2-6) ...
Setting up liblensfun-bin (0.3.2-6) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.10.2-1) ...
(base) ykarant@equality-HP-ZBook-15-G2:~$ lensfun-update-data
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/lensfun-update-data", line 46, in <module>
    import lensfun
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lensfun'
```

Ubuntu LTS latest current production. The recommended Sourceforge URL for lensfun shows open tickets from 2019 and nothing "current".  Although darktable (and thus lensfun) are available Ubuntu installation packages, are these in fact orphaned and effectively no longer supported?

Comment: Do you have any custom Python envirionments other than system installed Python set up?  Because the only reason it would not find the module is if you're using a different python than the current system Python is.

Comment: Not to the best of my knowledge, although I have other Python based applications and utilities.  Is there a mechanism to determine if any of these have installed such?   I thought that Python applications could be designed to bring whatever environment each needed without "stepping on" other such applications, e.g., if needed, an application individual "sandbox".

Comment: any luck on this? I have the same issue